# Gtk3 with Python, TextView rising multiple 'mark-set' signals

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

Consider the following example code, which puts a `TextView` inside a window and registers the `mark-set` event:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window(title='test')
text_view = Gtk.TextView()

def test (*args):
    print('test!')

win.add(text_view)
text_view.get_buffer().connect('mark-set', test)

win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

If I launch it, and I click on the visualized `TextView` **once** I get the debug output multiple times:

```
$ ./test.py 2>/dev/null
test!
test!
test!
test!
```

Do you know why this is happening? Is there a way of avoiding it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know **why** exactly it's happening, but I found something to help you understand, or use it to prevent duplicate actions in handler, using `mark.get_name()`. Here I changed your code, type some text and play with it (select some text, click somewhere, ...)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window(title='test')
text_view = Gtk.TextView()

def mark_set(buf, itr, mark):
    ### mark.get_name() ==> 'selection_bound' | 'insert' | None
    print('Time: %.2f,    Mark Name: %s'%(time.time()%100, mark.get_name()))

win.add(text_view)
text_view.get_buffer().connect('mark-set', mark_set)

win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```